# In Asp.net core , dotnet.exe publish command , fails to generate a .exe file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I download the Project opensourced at github location 
https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/tree/dev/test/E2ETests

When I try to publish the project using below command, it fails to generate E2ETest.exe file.

```
    dotnet.exe publish -o c:\..\E2EClient -c Release
```

Kindly can anyone help me with the same , I want to deploy the Published folder onto another machine.

Comment: A bit more info would be useful, do you get any errors? What is the output?

Comment: Thanks for looking into the issue , i found the answer to my question , from below comment by @pawel

Answer (score 2):

Tests are not compiled to an .exe - note that they don't have an entry point (i.e. Main method). They are compiled to a dll and then are being run with the xunit runner.